# Filter Json array

Tags: java, android, json

This is my first time working with json and I'm having a hard time trying to filter an array I'm trying to get all values (tienda) where id_estado=1.

Any clue how to approach this?

```
JA1= [{"id_estado":"1","tienda":"Aurrera"},{"id_estado":"1","tienda":"Walt-Mart"},{"id_estado":"1","tienda":"Chedraui"},{"id_estado":"1","tienda":"Soriana"},{"id_estado":"1","tienda":"Comercial MX"},{"id_estado":"1","tienda":"City Market"},{"id_estado":"2","tienda":"Walt-Mart"},{"id_estado":"2","tienda":"Chedraui"},{"id_estado":"2","tienda":"Aurrera"},{"id_estado":"2","tienda":"Superama"}]

            JSONArray JA1=new JSONArray(result1);
        JSONObject json1= null;
        name = new String[JA1.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < JA1.length(); i++) {
                 Log.d("LOG", "resultado name sin arreglo11 " + JA1);
                //name[i] = json1.getString("tienda");
                //name[i]=json1.getString("estado");
            }

        for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)
        {
            list2.add(name[i]);
            Log.d("LOG", "resultado name2 " + name[i]);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Hint:* If you are filtering the array, the resultant array will likely be smaller. The size of the resultant array will not be known up-front, so you should use an `ArrayList<String>`, not a `String[]`, to collection the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using kotlin, you can create an extension method and pass in a validation function as a parameter

```
fun JSONArray.filter(validate: (JSONObject) -> Boolean): List<JSONObject> {
    val retVal = mutableListOf<JSONObject>()
    for (i in 0.until(length())) {
        try {
            val jsonObject = getJSONObject(i)
            if (validate(jsonObject)) {
                retVal.add(jsonObject)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: $e")
        }
    }
    return retVal
}
```

You can use it like this

```
val filteredArray = jsonArray.filter { it.getString("bar") == "foo" }
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
    try {
        List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONArray ary = new JSONArray(/* your json here */);

        for (int i = 0; i < ary.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject obj = ary.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = obj.getString("id_estado");
            if (id.equals("1")) {
                filtered.add(obj.getString("tienda"));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
```

An explanation of this code:

- Create an `ArrayList` to hold the filtered values.
- Create a `JSONArray` from your json text.
- Iterate over each element in the array, pulling out a `JSONObject` each time.
- For each object, we get its `id_estado` property and check if it is equal to `"1"`.
- If it is, we add the `tienda` property to the list of filtered values.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < JA1.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
             name[i] = json_data.getString("tienda");

        }
```

we have to create object of each nested JSON item in the JSON using `JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);` that was missing in your case.